# Ada GNATprove Command_Line.Argument precondition fail

Tags: command-line, ada, gnat, spark-ada

I'm trying to write a simple verification code block to ensure the argument(Ada.Command_Line.Argument) and input from GetLine are valid, which in my case, I need all the characters in the input String to be numbers (0 to 9).

main.adb:

```
pragma SPARK_Mode (On);

with test_procedure;
with Ada.Command_Line;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Main is

   package CL   renames Ada.Command_Line;

   user_str : String  := CL.Argument(1);
   Flag     : Boolean := False;

begin

   if CL.Argument_Count = 1 then
      for I in user_str'Range loop
         case user_str(I) is
            when '0'..'9' => Flag := True;
            when others   => Flag := False; exit;
         end case;
      end loop;
   end if;

   if Flag then
      test_procedure.ToA(user_str);
      Put(user_str);
   end if ;

end Main;
```

test_procedure.ads:

```
package test_procedure with SPARK_Mode is
   procedure ToA(S : in out String) with
   Pre => (for all I in S'Range => S(I) >= '0' and S(I) <= '9');
end test_procedure;
```

test_procedure.adb

```
package body test_procedure with SPARK_Mode is
   procedure ToA(S : in out String) is
   begin
      for I in S'Range loop
         S(I) := 'a';
      end loop;
   end ToA;
end test_procedure;
```

The program works perfectly fine. If I input `./main 01234` it will return `aaaaa`, and if I input `./main f00` it will return nothing. However, when I use GNATprove (in GPS -> SPARK -> Prove All), it gives me `precondition might fail, cannot prove S(I) >= '0' (e.g. when I = 1 and user_str = (2 => '0', others => 'NUL'))`. I'm not sure why this happens since if the none digit character exists, the ToA procedure shouldn't be called.

Comment: What happens if you change your precondition to `(for all I in S'range => S (I) in '0' .. '9')`? That's a more Ada-like way to express it. Given the nature of the failure, though, it probably won't help.

Answer (score 2):

What seems missing is a [loop invariant](https://docs.adacore.com/spark2014-docs/html/ug/en/source/assertion_pragmas.html#loop-invariants) that shows the prover how the value of `Flag` (or `All_Digits` in the example below) relates to the part of the string that has been checked. In the example below, I refactored your example a little bit in order to isolate the code to be proved from the usage of the package `Ada.Command_Line`. This package has not been annotated and hence raises warnings during the proof session. The procedure `Check_Argument` itself can be proven in GNAT CE 2020.

**main.adb**

```
with Ada.Command_Line;
with Check_Argument;

procedure Main is
   package CL renames Ada.Command_Line;
begin
   if CL.Argument_Count = 1 then
      Check_Argument (CL.Argument (1));
   end if;   
end Main;
```

**check_argument.adb**

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Check_Argument (Arg : String) with SPARK_Mode is

   procedure To_A (S : in out String) with
     Pre => (for all I in S'Range => S(I) in '0' .. '9');

   ----------
   -- To_A --
   ----------

   procedure To_A (S : in out String) is
   begin
      for I in S'Range loop
         S (I) := 'a';
      end loop;
   end To_A;


   User_Str   : String  := Arg;
   All_Digits : Boolean := False;

   -- NOTE: All_Digits must be initialized as User_Str might have length 0.

begin
   for I in User_Str'Range loop

      All_Digits := User_Str (I) in '0'..'9';
      exit when not All_Digits;

      pragma Loop_Invariant
        (for all J in User_Str'First .. I => 
           User_Str (J) in '0' .. '9');

      pragma Loop_Invariant (All_Digits);

   end loop;   

   if All_Digits then
      To_A (User_Str);
      Put (User_Str);
   end if;

end Check_Argument;
```

**output** (prover)

```
check_argument.adb:6:40: info: index check proved
check_argument.adb:28:31: info: index check proved
check_argument.adb:32:10: info: loop invariant initialization proved
check_argument.adb:32:10: info: loop invariant preservation proved
check_argument.adb:33:22: info: index check proved
check_argument.adb:35:30: info: loop invariant initialization proved
check_argument.adb:35:30: info: loop invariant preservation proved
check_argument.adb:40:7: info: precondition proved
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll ever be able to prove this, since the call to CL.Argument might violate the function's precondition. You should do something like

```
User_Str : String := (if CL.Argument_Count > 0 then CL.Argument (1) else "");
```

You could use the full power of the SPARK language to simplify your code:

```
subtype Digit is Character range '0' .. '9';

Flag : constant Boolean := User_Str'Length > 0 and then
                           (for all I in User_Str'range => User_Str (I) in Digit);
```

eliminating the first `if` in Main, and the body of Toa could simply be

```
S := (S'range => 'a');
```

These get rid of unnecessary loops and the need to specify loop invariants to prove them, which might help your proof succeed.

Answer (score 2):

I think [Jeffrey’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62188418/40851) looks great, but these changes to your code let proof succeed:

- make `user_str` start at index 1 (the loop invariant becomes more difficult without this),

```
Str : constant String := CL.Argument(1);
user_str : String (1 .. Str'Length) := Str;
```

- add a loop invariant, like [DeeDee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62188248/40851)'s

```
for I in user_str'Range loop
   pragma Loop_Invariant
     (for all C of user_str (1 .. I - 1) => C in '0' .. '9');
```

The first change still has a problem, because we don’t know that `Argument_Count` is at least 1; this could be fixed by getting the argument in a `declare` block guarded by the check on `Argument_Count = 1`.